# Why I am getting 401 unauthorized however user is logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am creating a web api in .NET 5 in which a user can like a product added by another user to the database but can't like their own ( because that would be pointless). Following this line of thought, each product can be liked by many users but many users can like one product and here my first question arises if this relationship is one to many? If so I did some coding and debugging. My problem is when I try to get user by his username from User.Identity.Name I get 401 Unauthorized however my user is correctly logged in. I put Authorization on my LikeController class and I have passed credentials correctly in Postman.  Any suggestions tips to overcome this problem?

[image]

[image]

```
//User and product entity
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Product> LikedProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}


[Authorize]
    [HttpPost("add-to-favorites/{productId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddToFavorites(int productId)
    {
        var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(productId);

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        if (product.UserId == user.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest("You can't like your own product.");
        }

        if (user.LikedProducts.Contains(product))
        {
            return BadRequest("TYou have already liked this product.");
        }

        user.LikedProducts.Add(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are logging in correctly.  You have a _context which is Entity where you are reading a database.  You are getting Unauthorize because the query into the database is failing :  _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

Comment: There is a `return Unauthorized()` in line 45 if `user` is null. Have you double checked if the user is found by your query? Maybe the user names differ and `user` is null.

Comment: just debug your code and see exactly what you get in `User.Identity.Name`. Most probably is not what you expect, either is a different case and your db is case sensitive, the username also contains the domain, etc...